# why have I an error in the visual constructor?

Tags: php, html, constructor, elementor

I have an error notice in the visual constructor of my web page (jupiter)

That error says:

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'pro_widgets' in /home/customer/www/gedysa.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/api.php on line 164`

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'pro_widgets' in /home/customer/www/gedysa.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/api.php on line 167`

I have gone where apparently the problem is, in the php archive of jupiter plugin and it look like this:

```
164     $data['pro_widgets'] = [];
165     }
166
167     return $data['pro_widgets'];
```

but I dont know what to do.

Could somebody help me??

Comment: `$data` is a string instead of an array, which is why it's throwing that error. Since it's part of the elementor plugin, I would contact them for help, as any updates might be overwritten the next time you update the plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much, im goint to try contact them